# Seleccionar fotos desde álbumes de redes sociales

Tags: php, javascript, web, facebook, instagram

Estoy estudiando involucrarme en un proyecto que consiste en una aplicación web de revelados online y artículos personalizados como, tazas, planchas de madera, lienzos. Es decir, de esas que entras, eliges un artículo, le pones la foto que quieras y lo compras.

Uno de los requisitos por parte del cliente, es que la App tiene que tener la opción de seleccionar las fotos, además de desde el pc, desde los álbumes de las redes sociales, sobre todo, desde Facebook e Instagram, y es aquí donde veo el mayor problema, pues no encuentro nada de información, y a mí, la verdad es que no se me ocurre cómo hacerlo.

¿Alguien por ahí que me pueda orientar un poco?

Comment: Jous, te sugiero que le des un vistazo al [tour]. Te adelanto que la idea del sitio es que nos muestres tus avances, y que nos hagas preguntas puntuales, principalmente sobre errores. Lo que preguntas es demasiado amplio, pero como recomendación, podrías investigar sobre las APIs de Facebook e Instagram.